# How to search for a word that is split in two lines?

Tags: java, logic

I'm writing a program in java to search for a list of words(transaction numbers) in a .txt file. The .txt file can have any number of lines.

```
List<String> transactionList = new ArrayList<String>(
            Arrays.asList("JQ7P00049", "TM7P04797", "RT6P70037");
FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(filePath);
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        try {
            String readLine = bufferedReader.readLine();
            for (String transactionIndex : transactionList) {
                if (readLine != null) {
                    if (readLine.contains(transactionIndex)) {
                        System.out.println(transactionIndex + ": true");
                        readLine = bufferedReader.readLine();
                    } else {
                        readLine = bufferedReader.readLine();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

The programs runs fine except if the word is split between two lines, for example:

-------- JQ7P0
0049----------

that's obviously because the bufferedReader reads line by line and does the comparison of search string with the content present in that line.

Is there any way to handle this scenario?

Comment: You're not looping through the file here. How many lines can the file be? Is it always at least two lines? Can it be more?

Comment: oh! my bad i have made an edit in the program.

Comment: You're still not looping through the entire file. Can you please answer my question about the number of lines in the file, by [edit]ing your question?

Comment: do transaction numbers have the same length? if yes, why not read the file char by char omiting newline characters until that lenght and then compare

Comment: no, the transaction numbers can vary from 9-11 digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As durron597 mentioned, you weren't looping through the whole file, but here's a solution that assumes the file has at least 2 lines and that a transaction string doesn't span more than 2 lines.

It concatenates each line with the next, and searches for the strings in the concatenated lines. To prevent the same transaction from being printed twice, I added an additional check.

```
    List<String> transactionList = new ArrayList<String>( Arrays.asList("JQ7P00049", "TM7P04797", "RT6P70037") );
    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(filePath);
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
    try {
        // Search the first line
        String lastLine = bufferedReader.readLine();
        for (String transactionIndex : transactionList) {
            if (lastLine.contains(transactionIndex)) {
                System.out.println(transactionIndex + ": true");
            } 
        }
        String currentLine = null;

        // Search the remaining lines
        while((currentLine=bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            String combined = lastLine + currentLine;
            for (String transactionIndex : transactionList) {
                if (currentLine.contains(transactionIndex) || (!lastLine.contains(transactionIndex) && combined.contains(transactionIndex))) {
                    System.out.println(transactionIndex + ": true");
                } 
            }
            lastLine = currentLine;
        }

    } catch ( Exception e ) {
        System.out.println( e.getClass().getSimpleName() + ": " + e.getMessage() );
    } finally {
        bufferedReader.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This program has a second problem: You aren't going to read all the lines in longer files, because you have no loop that will loop through all the lines in the file.

That said, you can do this by reading two lines at once, and merging them together.

Here's a complete program:

```
private static final List<String> transactionList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(
    "JQ7P00049", "TM7P04797", "RT6P70037"));

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  String filePath = "test.txt";

  FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(filePath);
  BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

  try {
    String firstLine = bufferedReader.readLine();
    String secondLine = bufferedReader.readLine();
    if (secondLine == null) {
      checkLine(firstLine);
    }
    do {
      String combinedLine = firstLine + secondLine;
      checkLine(combinedLine);
      firstLine = secondLine;
    } while ((secondLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null);
  } finally {

  }
}

private static void checkLine(String combinedLine) {
  for (Iterator<String> iterator = transactionList.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
    String transactionIndex = iterator.next();
    if (combinedLine.contains(transactionIndex)) {
      System.out.println(transactionIndex + ": true");
      iterator.remove();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to not properly read the file, but rather reads as many lines as you have transaction numbers you're looking for. Assuming that this is not what you want, I have corrected it.

Also, I assume that an transaction number can span AT MOST two lines.

```
    List<String> transactionList = new ArrayList<String>(
                Arrays.asList("JQ7P00049", "TM7P04797", "RT6P70037"));
    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(filePath);
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
    String[] lastLines = {"",""};
    try {
        String readLine;
        while((readLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            lastLines[0] = lastLines[1];
            lastLines[1] = readLine;
            String combinedLastLines;
            combinedLastLines = lastLines[0] + lastLines[1];
            for (String transactionIndex : transactionList) {
                if (combinedLastLines.contains(transactionIndex) && !lastLines[0].contains(transactionIndex)) {
                    System.out.println(transactionIndex + ": true");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The general idea is to always combine two lines, and look whether the transaction number is in there. Let's have a look at the code:

```
String[] lastLines = {"",""};
```

This line defines an array which we will use to store the two most recently read lines.

```
while((readLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
```

This snippet reads as many lines as there are in your text file.

```
lastLines[0] = lastLines[1];
lastLines[1] = readLine;
String combinedLastLines;
combinedLastLines = lastLines[0] + lastLines[1];
```

This code is responsible for replacing the oldest line in the array, and push the currently readLine into the array. Those last two lines are then combined to one String!

```
if (combinedLastLines.contains(transactionIndex) && !lastLines[0].contains(transactionIndex)) {
```

Here we are searching the combined lines for the transaction numbers. But: when a transaction number is not spanning multiple lines, we might accidently find it twice. Therefore, the second check is for ensuring we did not find the transaction before.

Hope this is what you're looking for!